# Do the arcane items disappear whenever starting a NG+?

Tags: bloodborne

So I finally beaten new game, went into NG+

I thought it would be a fun idea to work on my arcane skill and try out some of the arcane items, now I cant find them! Not in my inventory, and not in the chest in hunters dream!

Do the arcane items disappear whenever starting a NG+?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, arcane items, also known as [Hunter's Tools](http://bloodborne.wiki.fextralife.com/Items), don't disappear from your inventory when rolling into NG+. You can continue to pick up the same arcane items and they will automatically be stored in your storage chest in the Hunter's Dream, as you can only keep one in your inventory at a time.

Hunter's Tools should be listed among your consumables, near the bottom of the list, not among your weapons.